# How to install ppstream on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

How do I install ppstream on 12.04?

Can someone give me a solution?Thank you!

When I type sudo apt-get install ppstream

I got this error:

```
conan51xd@conan51xd-Lenovo-B470:~$ sudo apt-get install ppstream
[sudo] password for conan51xd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ppstream
conan51xd@conan51xd-Lenovo-B470:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

[Install this in software centre](http://download.ppstream.com/ppstream_1.0.0-1_i386.deb)

Comment: I get this error:

Comment: The package is of bad quality The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.

Comment: http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/167 have a look at that

Comment: But the problem still have,thank you anyway

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.