# How to install mplayer required by ppstream

Tags: software-installation

How do I install ppstream? I tried getting the files and installing it. PPStream for GNU/Linux Ubuntu 8.04+ Distro. I get:

```
Cannot install'mplayer:i386'
```

I also tried going to Software Centre > search > mpayer
installing that then try it again. I still get the same message.

I search on askubuntu.com for ppstream and also Google
all I get is http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/167
or 
[How to install ppstream on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163923/how-to-install-ppstream-on-12-04)

Comment: Could you provide links to this ppstream!

Comment: Err, I see a problem trying to install something for ubuntu **8.04**..

Comment: I found this ppstream, it seems this is a dependencies issues. When installing its dependencies. You enter dependencie hell. Meaning, a mess

Comment: Further reading: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: http://dl.pps.tv/pps_linux_download.html

Answer (score 1):

I successfully downloaded and installed PPStream. You can use either:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget http://download.ppstream.com/linux/PPStream.deb
sudo gdebi PPStream.deb
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-gui libqt4-network libqt4-webkit libqt4-xml mplayer
wget http://download.ppstream.com/linux/PPStream.deb
sudo dpkg -i PPStream.deb
```

Before starting it, you have to do the following:

```
sudo /opt/pps/bin/PPStream  ## otherwise fuse won't work
sudo killall PPStream
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.pps
```

Comment: I tried doing it but it doesn't seem to work for me.
could it be I have to uninstall it first?
if so how do I do it. am kinda new to this.

Comment: @user238762 it depends on how you installed.

Comment: @user238762 sudo apt-get remove ppstream

Answer (score 1):

The following deb file seem to work, ignore the error and you should be good to go

```
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/58988381/ppstream_1.0.0-3lucid2_amd64.deb   
sudo dpkg -i ppstream_1.0.0-3lucid2_amd64.deb
```

screenshot: [image]

Comment: for some reason it didn't work for me. I get 

------------------------------------------------

dpkg: error processing ppstream (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ppstream
--------------------------------------

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge ppstream`, then try again.

Comment: use apt-get -f install to solve dependency problems. After that your program is fully installed

Answer (score 0):

This ppa contains packages for 14.04 and 13.10
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntukylin-members/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntukylin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enter in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer:i386*deb
```

and this might work fine this way.